# How to use COLLATE (T-SQL) with LIKE and findAll in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got the following script in Sequelize:

```js
findAll(Peope, {
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { firstName: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
      { lastName:  { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
    ]
  }
});
```

Which generates the WHERE clause below:

```sql
WHERE
  (
    [Player].[firstName] LIKE N'%test%'
    OR [Player].[lastName] LIKE N'%test%'
  )
```

I'd like to add COLLATE to remove accent-sensitive searching, so my final SQL code should look like this:

```sql
WHERE
  (
    [Player].[firstName] COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI LIKE N'%test%'
    OR [Player].[lastName] COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI LIKE N'%test%'
  )
```

How can I achieve this with Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize does not directly support COLLATE in the where clause, but you can use `Sequelize.literal` to inject raw SQL into your query.

Like this:

```
findAll(Peope, {
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      Sequelize.literal(`[Player].[firstName] COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI LIKE N'%${search}%'`),
      Sequelize.literal(`[Player].[lastName] COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI LIKE N'%${search}%'`)
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I improved it a bit by letting Sequelize escape characters for me: 

`[Op.or]: [ Sequelize.literal(``[Player].[firstName] COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI``, 'LIKE', ``%${search}%`` ), ... ]`